# PHP shell_exec 'sudo mount -t ntfs-3g' fails for www-data despite proper permissions. Yet same command succeeds on manual terminal run . Why?

Tags: php, linux, shell

I'm attempting to mount NTFS devices read-only via PHP using `shell_exec()` but I'm facing with the following error.

> ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Device or resource busy

Despite confirming that no processes are using the device and the device is not already mounted, the command fails when executed through PHP. Intriguingly, when I run the same command manually in my terminal, it succeeds and mounts the device.

Here's a code snippet of my test.php script

```
$command = "/usr/bin/sudo /bin/mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda1 /mnt/ntfs/sda1 2>&1";
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo "Output: $output";
```

First I've tried command how I type on normal terminal, but it didn't work. So, I decided to try to full paths of commands, but nope nothing changed.

I've also granted full permissions to the www-data user in /etc/sudoers and ensured ownership of the /www/html folder, but the issue persists.

Any insights into why the PHP execution is failing despite manual success would be greatly appreciated.